# Show related posts on single.php, grouped by taxonomy terms, with Advanced Custom Field post object selected

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-custom-fields, groupby

I have posts of custom taxonomy called Areas with terms such as Articles, Presentations, News etc. These terms are applied to the normal post-type "post".

Under a custom-post-type called "Company", I added an [Advanced Custom Field Post Object](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/post-object/) with the field name `associated_items` to select posts related to this Company.

Currently I have this function on my `single-company.php` which shows the posts selected in ACF field `associated_items`...

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field('associated_items');?>
<?php if( $post_objects ): ?>
        <div class="relatedposts">
            <h3>Related Posts</h3>
            <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): ?>
            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'excerpt' ); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><!-- div.relatedposts -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; // end if( $post_objects ) ?>
```

The above code only outputs the posts selected in the ACF custom field `associated_items` but in chronological order whereas I'd like it to be grouped according to taxonomy terms, for example like the following:

### Posts related to the Company

Articles

- a post under the area "Articles"
- another post under the area "Articles"
- and another post under the area "Articles"

Presentations

- a post under the area "Presentations"
- another post under the area "Presentations"
- and another post under the area "Presentations"

News

- a post under the area "News"
- another post under the area "News"
- and another post under the area "News"

Many many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating 3 separate ['associated_items'] fields instead of 1.

For Example:

- ['associated_articles'] & "Filter for taxonomy term: Articles"
- ['associated_presentations'] & "Filter for taxonomy term: Presentations"
- ['associated_news'] & "Filter for taxonomy term: News"

*Note: Filtering for the taxonomy term, limits the related posts available to choose from as well, which results in a better user experience*

Then change the code above to be used for each field.
***For Example:***

```
<h2>Posts related to the Company</h2>
<?php $assoc_articles = get_field('associated_articles');?>
<?php if( $assoc_articles ): ?>
    <div class="relatedposts">
        <h3>Articles</h3>
        <?php foreach( $ass_articles as $article): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($article); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'excerpt' ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div><!-- div.relatedposts -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

```
<?php $assoc_presentations = get_field('associated_presentations');?>
<?php if( $assoc_presentations ): ?>
    <div class="relatedposts">
        <h3>Presentations</h3>
        <?php foreach( $assoc_presentations as $presentation ): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($presentation ); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'excerpt' ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div><!-- div.relatedposts -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

```
<?php $assoc_news = get_field('associated_news');?>
<?php if( $assoc_news ): ?>
    <div class="relatedposts">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <?php foreach( $assoc_news as $news_item ): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($news_item ); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'excerpt' ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div><!-- div.relatedposts -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'm assuming you are using the above code sample because you prefer it.  However, if all you need is a link to the post, you don't actually need to setup_postdata()... you could simply use the $post->ID and then just loop through the results using something like:

```
<?php foreach( $assoc_news as $news_item ): 
$news_ID = $news_item->ID; ?>
<li><a href="<?php get_permalink($news_ID ); ?>"><?php get_the_title($news_ID ); ?></a></li>... etc
```

I hope that helps.